# Using the result of inner query in the same query

Tags: sql

I am trying to reuse the nested select query aliased PrevClose in a separate calculation. However I get invalid column name. Does this mean there's no way to reuse the result and since I need to do a couple of calculations on it I have to rerun that inner query two more times?

```
 SELECT TOP 1000 [DateEntered]
      ,[Symbol]
      ,[Side]
      ,[Gross]
      ,[NET]
      ,[Shares]
      ,[Entry]
      ,[TimeIn]
      ,[Exit]
      ,[TimeOut]
      , B.Industry
      , (
        SELECT TOP 1 C.[Close] 
        FROM EndOfDay AS C 
        Where C.Symbol = A.Symbol 
            AND C.[Date] < A.DateEntered 
        ORDER BY C.[Date] DESC
      ) AS PrevClose
      , (A.[Entry] - PrevClose) AS Opg
  FROM [Analytics].[dbo].[TradeExec] AS A 
  Join finviz AS B ON A.Symbol = B.Ticker
  WHERE A.DateEntered < '2013-01-01'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `outer apply`:

```
SELECT TOP 1000  . . .,
       prev.PrevClose,
       ( A.[Entry] - prev.PrevClose) AS Opg
  FROM [Analytics].[dbo].[TradeExec] A JOIN
       finviz B
       ON A.Symbol = B.Ticker OUTER APPLY
       (SELECT TOP 1 C.[Close] as PrevClose
        FROM EndOfDay C 
        WHERE C.Symbol = A.Symbol  AND C.[Date] = A.DateEntered 
        ORDER BY C.[Date] DESC
      ) prev
  WHERE A.DateEntered < '2013-01-01';
```

This will also let you get multiple columns from the previous day, if you like.

Comment: My first encounter with OUTER APPLY. Adding this link for reference http://www.mediaagility.com/2013/what-is-cross-apply-and-outer-apply-in-sql-server/

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Sorry - you are absolutely right. I had misread your answer, so I deleted my comment when I noticed I was wrong. At least I almost got to correct one of the greats like yourself :)

Answer (score 3):

To reuse the value, consider taking your query (minus the field with the calculation) and placing it in a sub-query. Then you can use the new column from your sub-query in the outer query with as many calculations as you want.

```
SELECT *, (A.[Entry] - PrevClose) AS Opg
FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1000
    [DateEntered]
        ,[Symbol]
        ,[Side]
        ,[Gross]
        ,[NET]
        ,[Shares]
        ,[Entry]
        ,[TimeIn]
        ,[Exit]
        ,[TimeOut]
        , B.Industry
        , (
        SELECT TOP 1 C.[Close] 
        FROM EndOfDay AS C 
        Where C.Symbol = A.Symbol 
            AND C.[Date] = A.DateEntered 
        ORDER BY C.[Date] DESC
        ) AS PrevClose
    FROM [Analytics].[dbo].[TradeExec] AS A 
    Join finviz AS B ON A.Symbol = B.Ticker
    WHERE A.DateEntered < '2013-01-01'
) T
```